# the difference between $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

What is the difference between $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$?

I am reading from some notes and author denotes the empty set by $\{\emptyset\}$. I am getting confused as definition says

> In mathematics, and more specifically set theory, the empty set or
>   null set is the unique set having no elements

I think $\{\emptyset\}$ is wrong notation as that implies that it has one element. More specifically it should be the notation of power set of $\emptyset$

Comment: One is the empty set, and the other isn't.

Comment: The empty set is **not** denoted as $\{\varnothing\}$, but as $\{\}$ or as $\varnothing$. It contains no elements. This in contrast with $\{\varnothing\}$ which contains $\varnothing$ as element.

Comment: Can you link to the notes you're reading?

Comment: @AlexKruckman It is the hand written notes which I got from my friend. I am self studying set theory. I can send you the camera picture if you want.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician Oh, I see. No, you don't need to send me a picture. Maybe it's possible your friend took down the notes incorrectly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{\varnothing\}$ is a set containing the emptyset. The other is the emptyset, it does not contain elements.

Comment: "..emptyset" or "empti-element" ?

Comment: Can you define "empti-element"?

Comment: @Gibbs I have reached the daily upvote limit. I will upvote the answer later. I appreciate your answer. Thanks for taking your time. Cheers!!!

Comment: @Gibbs: got it, thanks.